# Using PDO to insert data into database - avoid data insert from other people

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo, insert

I'm using PDO to insert data into my database. I already got the following code which works fine, but the problem is that I'm supposed to be the only one who is allowed to insert data into the database. As everyone can find example.com/blog.html, anyone could just add blog posts to my website. How I am supposed to avoid this kind of situation?

**blog.html (My form)**

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="blog post" action="insert.php" method="post">

<label for "id">Id: </label>
<input type="text" name="id">
<br>    
<label for "title">Title: </label>
<input type="text" name="title">
<br>    
<label for "year">Year: </label>
<input type="text" name="year">
<br>
<label for "text">Text: </label>
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="text"></textarea>
<br>    
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**insert.php (My php code)**

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbexample', 'userexample', 'passwexample', array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>"SET NAMES utf8;SET time_zone = 'Europe/London'"));

$sql = "INSERT INTO `tableexample` (id, title, year, text)
                                        VALUES (:id, :title, :year, :text)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
$stmt->bindParam(":title", $title);
$stmt->bindParam(":year", $year);
$stmt->bindParam(":text", $text);

$form = $_POST;
$id = $form[ 'id' ];                    
$titel = $form[ 'title' ];                  
$jaar = $form[ 'year' ];                
$tekst = $form[ 'text' ];                   


$result = $stmt->execute();

if($result) {
    echo "Your message has been posted";

    }// end if
else {
    echo '0 results';
    }// end else

?>
```

Comment: By using some kind of authentication mechanism on your website, so that only a valid logged-in user can invoke this action.  It has nothing to do with your database access, you just don't have any sort of username/password protection for your page.

Comment: So basically I need to create a secure login script in PHP and Mysql and then give some users permission to insert data to the database? That's a lot of work but I guess there's no other way to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as @David suggested, it does not have to be so complex, you just need athentication mechanism, for example you can add a field just for you to input a secret key. And run the pdo code only when the keys match.

**HTML**

```
<label for "key">Enter key: </label>
<input type="text" name="key">
<br>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['key']) && $_POST['key'] === MY_KEY){
   //PDO code here ...
}else{
   echo "Incorrect Key , you are not authorized to add blog entries";
}
```

`MY_KEY` is just a constant you can define in a config file you include in your script

```
define('MY_KEY' , 'HDIhdihfsiX872**e72!!{dsdsf');
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code. I didn't think of something like that myself. It works fine!